# Azure functions are very slow to start

Tags: web, azure-functions

The following is the response time of the same function:

- 3.9s (2021/6/17 13:58:10)
- 355.5ms (2021/6/17 13:59:37)
- 107.1ms (2021/6/17 13:59:39)

It gets faster the second or third time, but the first time always takes a few seconds (I'm using dedicated hosting plan, so it's not cold start).

The function simply gets data from a Cosmos DB using bindings and return it. I think Cosmos DB is not slow:

[image: response duration]

**index.js**

```
module.exports = function(context){
    context.res = {body: context.bindings.room.comments}
    context.done()
}
```

**function.json**

```
{
    "bindings": [
        {
            "authLevel": "anonymous",
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "name": "req",
            "methods": ["get"],
            "route": "rooms/{roomId}/comments"
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out",
            "name": "res"
        },
        {
            "name": "room",
            "type": "cosmosDB",
            "direction": "in",
            "databaseName": "main",
            "collectionName": "rooms",
            "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDbConnectionString",
            "partitionKey": "{roomId}",
            "id": "{roomId}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to speed this up?

Related question: [CDN to cache Web API responses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68012947)

Comment: Are you using consumption plan? If yes, then the behavior would due to cold start. You can move to premium consumption plan with minimum running instance.

Comment: Are you trying to increase the value of `Always Ready Instances`?

Comment: You can test by removing route and room cosmosDB binding. One of my NodeJS Azure Function was creating the same issue,